# c# Azure MVC check if blob exists from controller Calling .Result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, model-view-controller, azure-blob-storage

I need to check for the existance of a blob in an MVC controller action, and   I'm trying to do it the asynchronous way with no success.

If I do the check synchronously it's working fine and I get the desired result, and the code is the next:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id, string size)
{
    string redirectUrl;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(assetBlobUrl)) assetBlobUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssetBlobUrl"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assetBlobUrl))
    {
        bool blobExists = _blobExists(size, id);
        if (blobExists)
        {
            redirectUrl = string.Format(assetBlobUrl, size, id);
            return new PermanentRedirectResult(redirectUrl);
        }
    }

    return ResponseImageNotFound();
}

private bool _blobExists(string size, string assetId)
{
    var container = serviceClient.GetContainerReference("images");
    CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(size + "/" + assetId + ".jpg");
    bool checkBlobExists = blockBlob.Exists();

    return checkBlobExists;
}
```

The asynchronous (not working) version is the next:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id, string size)
{
    string redirectUrl;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(assetBlobUrl)) assetBlobUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssetBlobUrl"];
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(assetBlobUrl))
    {
        bool blobExists = _blobExists(size, id).Result;
        if (blobExists)
        {
            redirectUrl = string.Format(assetBlobUrl, size, id);
            return new PermanentRedirectResult(redirectUrl);
        }
    }

    return ResponseImageNotFound();
}

private async Task<bool> _blobExists(string size, string assetId)
{
    bool blobExists = await container.GetBlockBlobReference(size + "/" + assetId + ".jpg").ExistsAsync();

    return blobExists;
}
```

But this last way the web keeps loading and the line with the ExistsAsync never finishes so the next return is never hit.

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like classic deadlock to me. Calling `.Result` is generally a bad idea. Can you change your method to `public async Task<ActionResult> Index` instead and do `await _blobExists...`  instead of `.Result` ?

Comment: You are the man @NibblyPig! Now it works, so thank you very much, and if you write it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in calling `.Result`, which is generally a bad practice because it can be avoided.

When the method `_blobExists` does its `await`, it goes away, performs the task, then tries to come back and resume. The problem is your previous call to `.Result` has blocked the thread because it's waiting for `_blobExists` to finish getting the `Result`. So the `_blobExists` await is waiting for the thread to be free so it can continue running the method and return your result.

This means you end up with a deadlock scenario, both are waiting for each other.

Fortunately we can define controller actions as async, so changing the method signature to   :

`public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string id, string size)` should fix it.

However you still need to be careful, if you're not using .NET Core then you should specify that you don't need the same synchronization context otherwise the problem can still occur, by putting `.ConfigureAwait(false)` on your `await` line.